# How do i read specific from one specific index to another?

Tags: c, fgets

I need to write some code that would allow me to read a string that was `input` by a user using `fgets()` but the first character is info about what the program should do.

For example in the program that i'm writing, if `input[0] ==  'p'` i want it to add to a struct the characters that follow it in `input [2]` through `input[4]` but every way i've tried to do it has failed. Anyone know how i can separate parts of a string?

Comment: Show the ways that have "failed" and explain how they failed.

Comment: You did something wrong in the code you didn't show. That's about all we can tell you so far. Please take the [tour] and read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. Then [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: `memcpy(dest, input + 2, 3);`? Draw out the `input` array on paper, and you will see why `input + 2` makes sense.

Comment: Also remember that strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. A string of three characters really need space for *four* characters to fit the null-terminator character `'\0'` at the end (which you might have to add explicitly yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int startIndex = 2;
int lastIndex = 4;
char answer[lastIndex - startIndex];

for (int i = startIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
    answer[i-startIndex] = input[i];
}
```

This grabs every character within the start and last index

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just because you're smart doesn't mean you have to brag about it, in other words, I fixed my answer

Comment: It's not about bragging, it's about giving you a chance to correct your answer.